# How to exclude a specific row from an SQL Count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to exclude a certain row from a `COUNT` in SQL Server. This is what I have:

```
SELECT COUNT(GuestId)TotalBooked
FROM GuestStayDetails
WHERE (@ArrivalDate = ArrivalDate)
   OR (@DepartureDate = DepartureDate) 
   OR (@ArrivalDate < ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate = DepartureDate) 
   OR (@ArrivalDate = ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate < DepartureDate)
   OR (@ArrivalDate < ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate > DepartureDate)
   OR (@ArrivalDate < DepartureDate AND @DepartureDate > DepartureDate)
   OR (@ArrivalDate BETWEEN ArrivalDate AND DATEADD(Day, -1, DepartureDate))
   OR (@DepartureDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -1, ArrivalDate) AND DepartureDate)
  AND Student = 1
  AND Cancelled = 0
  AND GuestStayDetails.GuestId != @GuestId;
```

If I remove the last `AND GuestStayDetails.GuestId != @GuestId;` it gives me the expected `COUNT` however I must exclude one of the `GuestID`s. Any suggestions?

Comment: You are missing a set of brackets for the logic to work correctly - you need brackets around **ALL** the `OR` conditions to ensure they work as expected.

Comment: What is the logic you are trying to implement?

Comment: Sample data and expected results are required for us to understand your logic.

Comment: Im to count the number of bookings inhouse during specific dates

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for overlapping time intervals -- as well as your parentheses problem.  If that is the case, you can significantly simplify the query:

```
WHERE @ArrivalDate <= DepartureDate AND
      @DepartureDate >= ArrivalDate AND
      Student = 1 AND
      Cancelled = 0 AND
      GuestStayDetails.GuestId <> @GuestId
```

This eliminates the need for any parentheses at all.

Comment: No The query has to be that way. I need to find out if someone is booked during specific dates...which include before the arrival, after arrival, before departure, after departure and during arrival and departure

Comment: @Paula1999 . . . That is what this logic does.

Comment: Yes thank you. I tried this and it worked for me!! Thank you for simplifying this for me. I did change it to ```@ArrivalDate < DepartureDate AND
      @DepartureDate > ArrivalDate AND``` so that it wouldnt flag up anyone who was arriving on the departure day or departing on the arrival day. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you need to add some parenthesis around the -OR- conditions. Can you test this and let us know if it works? Note the opening and closing parenthesis around the -OR- clauses.

```
SELECT COUNT(GuestId)TotalBooked
FROM GuestStayDetails
WHERE (
        (@ArrivalDate = ArrivalDate)
     OR (@DepartureDate = DepartureDate) 
     OR (@ArrivalDate < ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate = DepartureDate) 
     OR (@ArrivalDate = ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate < DepartureDate)
     OR (@ArrivalDate < ArrivalDate AND @DepartureDate > DepartureDate)
     OR (@ArrivalDate < DepartureDate AND @DepartureDate > DepartureDate)
     OR (@ArrivalDate BETWEEN ArrivalDate AND DATEADD(Day, -1, DepartureDate))
     OR (@DepartureDate BETWEEN DATEADD(Day, -1, ArrivalDate)AND DepartureDate) 
  )
  AND Student = 1
  AND Cancelled = 0
  AND GuestStayDetails.GuestId != @GuestId;
```

Comment: Yes this is working for me!! Thank you very much for your help!